# Is it possible to move the abstract into a separate document for papaja?

Tags: r, papaja

The abstract is often the longest section in the YAML in a papaja Rmd, and I was wondering if it was possible to move this off into a separate document (e.g. another Rmd file) and include it via reference instead (just as other chapters can be).

Comment: You should include a minimal papaja Rmd document in your question.  Then people who are new to papaja but not to R Markdown could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options: Text-references are built into **papaja**, but are a little more limited than using an external Lua-filter.

## Text-references

You can use **bookdown** [text-references](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#text-references) for this. This way you can move the abstract into the body of the document.

```markdown
---
title    : "Title"

abstract : "(ref:abstract)"

output   : papaja::apa6_pdf
---

(ref:abstract) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Similarly, you could use an inline code chunk for the text reference to put the abstract into a separate document.

```markdown
(ref:abstract) `r readlines()`
```

A limitation of this approach is that

> The paragraph must not be wrapped into multiple lines, and should not end with a white space.

## Lua-filters

A more flexible alternative is to use [this Lua-filter](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/abstract-to-meta) that uses an abstract section from the document body.

```markdown
---
title: "Title"

output:
  papaja::apa6_pdf:
    pandoc_args: ["--lua-filter", "path/to/abstract-to-meta.lua"]
---

# Abstract

The abstract text includes this.

* * * *

This text is the beginning of the document.
```

Here, the horizontal rule `* * * *` marks the end of the abstract. Again, here you could use a code chunk to include an external file.

````markdown
# Abstract

```{r}
#| child: "path/to/abstract.md"
```

* * * *
````